# SQL batch insert, avoid duplicates, no PK

Tags: c#, sql

I was given a task to insert over 1000 rows with 4 columns. The table in question does not have a `PK` or `FK`. Let's say it contains columns `ID`, `CustomerNo`, `Description`. The records needed to be inserted can have the same `CustomerNo` and `Description` values.

I read about importing data to a temporary table, comparing it with the real table, removing duplicates, and moving new records to the real table.

I also could have 1000 queries that check if such a record already exists and insert data if it does not. But I'm too ashamed to try that out for obvious reasons.

I'm not expecting any specific code, because I did not give any specific details. What I'm hoping for is some pseudocode or general advice for completing such tasks. I can't wait to give some upvotes!

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key - it's not a table* - add a PK !

Comment: What is the requirement when duplicates are found?  (1) Entire batch should fail, (2) Only those rows that are not duplicates should be inserted, (3) Only one row, picked at random, should be inserted per duplicate, (4) Only one row, based on specific criteria (e.g. the lowest CustomerNo wins), should be inserted per duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the idea is, you don't want to insert an entry if there's already an entry with the same ID?

If so, after you import your data into a temporary table, you can accomplish what you're looking for in the `where` clause of a select statement:

```
insert into table
    select ID, CustomerNo, Description from #data_source
    where (#data_source.ID not in (select table.ID from table))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you to load the data into a temp table or variable table. Then you can do a "Select Into" using the distinct key word which will removed the duplicated records.

Answer (score 0):

you will always need to read the target table, unless you bulk load the target table into a temp table(in this point you will have two temp tables) compare both, eliminate duplicates and then insert in target table, but even this is not accurate, because you can have a new insert in the target table while you do this.